# python-3.x list of strings in API function, gives error

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I am working with Arduino IoT Cloud API and I have this documentation: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/iot/api/?_gl=1*kbtgoy*_ga*MTcwNDAxMTQ4LjE2OTI2MTU1MDc.*_ga_NEXN8H46L5*MTY5NDA2OTcwNi4zMy4xLjE2OTQwNzA3NDMuMC4wLjA.#api-SeriesV2-seriesV2HistoricData

I am trying to call the seriesV2HistoricData specifically. So far I seem to have gotten the datetime string parameter correct by (lazily) pasting from the curl example, but I am struggling with the "properties" parameter which seems to be an array of strings. I have tried using a regular list with strings:

```
api_series_instance.series_v2_historic_data("2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00", ["046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91", "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91"], "2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00")
```

this gives error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I have tried with the array import as well:

```
import array as arr
api_series_instance.series_v2_historic_data("2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00", arr.array('u',["046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91", "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91"]), "2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00")
```

This gives error: TypeError: array item must be unicode character

I feel I am not using the array version properly, but there is also no typecode for strings? Shouldn't a list be doable regardless?

One way or another I am implementing it wrong... Either I am misusing the list or array, or I am misinterpreting the properties parameter in the documentation?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## API Usage

I assume that you're using the `arduino-iot-client` package.  If that is the case, you are using the `series_v2_historic_data` method incorrectly.  According to the [documentation](https://github.com/arduino/iot-client-py/blob/master/docs/apis/tags/SeriesV2Api.md#series_v2_historic_data) in the project's [repository](https://github.com/arduino/iot-client-py), you need to pass (at least) a `HistoricDataRequest` object to that particular method.  The example shown in the documentation, however, appears to be incorrect --- the `_from` parameter of `HistoricDataRequest` is actually named `from`.  Since `from` is a [Python keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers), you need to do some extra work to pass in that argument.  For your example data, this can be done as follows:

```py
import iot_api_client
from iot_api_client.model.historic_data_request import HistoricDataRequest
# Other imports ...

# API setup ...
api_series_instance = ...

body = HistoricDataRequest(
    **{"from": "2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00",},
    properties=[
        "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91",
        "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91",
    ],
    to="2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00",
)
try:
    api_response = api_series_instance.series_v2_historic_data(body=body)
except iot_api_client.ApiException as e:
    # Exception handling ...
```

Here, we are creating a dictionary with a single key-value pair, the key being the string `"from"`, and the value being the desired value of the `from` argument: `{"from": "2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00",}`.  Then, using the [`**expression` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), we pass the key-value pairs in this dictionary as keyword arguments to `HistoricDataRequest`.  (There is a short explanation of this syntax in the ["Unpacking Argument Lists" section of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).)

## Array Usage

The array provided by Python's `array` module cannot store a sequence of strings in a way that is as simple to use as a `list` of strings.  In most Python use cases, an array should not be used to store strings.

The `array` type is intended for storing basic *fixed-sized* values compactly (i.e. contiguously in memory), and the types of values that can be stored in them are limited to those listed in the [module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).  In general, strings do not have a fixed size (i.e. two arbitrary strings can have different lengths), and, therefore, there is not much benefit in attempting to store them in an array-like structure.

Most notably, for an array of any fixed-sized type, the memory location of any element can easily be calculated from its index (and the size of an element).  This is not possible when storing arbitrarily sized strings in an array (assuming that the characters that make up the strings are stored in the array).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It clears some things up when I look at the github

I tried implementing:
`body = HistoricDataRequest(
    _from="2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00",
    properties=[
        "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91",
        "046b6c7f-0b8a-43b9-b35d-6489e6daee91",
    ],
    to="2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00",
)`
but I get an error when running: iot_api_client.exceptions.ApiTypeError: HistoricDataRequest is missing 1 required argument: ['from']

Using "from" as parameter give error: Expected Expression. from seems to be recognized as some sort of operation as well

Comment: @Daddedebad The example on GitHub appears to be wrong (or outdated).  I've updated my answer to use the "from" parameter rather than the "_from" parameter.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding again,

The thing with using "from" as a parameter is that my Python interpreter recognise it as the keyword from, as in "from x import y" rather than as an actual parameter... It says "Expected expression Pylance".

Comment: In the code it says the class is generated by OpenAPI.

This is what one site says about using such keywords as parameters: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp

I'm trying to see what the proper documentation says on this as well.

But it seems like not a single human has touched this class before... That seems weird to me but I feel that is the case the more I look into it...

Comment: Sorry I missed the added text in your first response! It works now! Thank you so much!